# Open link that comes from text turned into clickable link

Tags: jquery, automation, clickable

I am trying to automatically open a link (plain text initially) with jQuery.

In the html code the link is written this way:

```
<p><strong>Page URL:</strong><br />
https://www.google.com/</p>
```

I used this code to turn the text into a clickable link:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('p').eq(7).html($('p').eq(7).html().replace(/(https?:\/\/.+?)(?:\s|$)/ig, '<a href="$1">$1</a> '));

    });

})(jQuery);
```

I tried to adapt some other code that I use successfully used on already clickable links but I just can't figure it out:

```
this.$ = this.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
var baseUrl = "http://www.google.com/";
var matchingLinks = $( "a[href*='" + baseUrl + "']" );
$(matchingLinks).each(
    function(index)
    {
        window.open( $(this).attr( "href" ) );
    }
);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JQuery. This code can help you.

```
function htmlchars(string) {return string.replace(/[\x00-\x1f\xff-\uffff]/g,function(v) {return "&#" + v.charCodeAt() + ";"})};
document.documentElement.replace(/https?:\/\/.+?(?:\s|$)/gi,function(v){return "<a href=\"" + htmlchars(v) + "\">" + htmlchars(v) + "</a>"});
```

I don't know it is working. I couldn't try it.